# Using dplyr, finding if selected column values are matching with other column value in R data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame, having more than 150 numbers of column, say for example

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Andy", "Bob", "Andy", "Cha", "Andy", "Bob", "Dil"), 
                 num = c(1,NA, 0,NA, 1, NA, 0), 
                 place=c("Andy", "Bob", "Andy", "Cha", "Andy", "Bob", "Dil"))
```

It shows the data frame as

```
name num place
1 Andy   1  Andy
2  Bob  NA   Bob
3 Andy   0  Andy
4  Cha  NA   Cha
5 Andy   1  Andy
6  Bob  NA   Bob
7  Dil   0   Dil
```

Now I have seen that, although the variable names `name` and `place` are different, the values of column 1 (`name`) and column 3 (`place`) are same. There are  150 numbers of columns in my data frame. So I want to find out the variable which represents the similar type of information as the variable named  `name` (column 1).

Comment: You can subset extras out with `duplicated.default`, e.g. `df[!duplicated.default(df)]`

Comment: There are 150 numbers of columns in my data frame. Variable "place" is one of them. So I want to find out the variable which represents the similar type of information as the variable named ‘name’(column1).  At the initial level, variable "place " is unknown to me. I have to find out the variable "place" column

Comment: If you want the repeats, `names(df)[duplicated.default(df)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code if you are interested in getting the positions of columns with the same values of column one:

```
which(apply(df[, -1], 2, function(x)all(x == df[, 1])))
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Alistaire's comment, a complete solution extracting the duplicate and non-duplicate columns looks like this.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Andy", "Bob", "Andy", "Cha", "Andy", "Bob", "Dil"), 
                 num = c(1,NA, 0,NA, 1, NA, 0), 
                 place=c("Andy", "Bob", "Andy", "Cha", "Andy", "Bob", "Dil"),
                 num2 = c(1,NA, 0,NA, 1, NA, 0))
library(magrittr)
# duplicated columns
df[1,duplicated.default(df)] %>% names(.)
# non-duplicated columns
df[1,!duplicated.default(df)] %>% names(.)
```

...and the output:

```
> df[1,duplicated.default(df)] %>% names(.)
[1] "place" "num2" 
> df[1,!duplicated.default(df)] %>% names(.)
[1] "name" "num" 
>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if two columns are strictly identical, use `identical()`, e.g.

```
purrr::map_lgl(df, ~ identical(., df$name))
```

You get:

```
 name   num place 
 TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```